# PHP getting LDAP entryUUID via adodb

Tags: php, ldap, adodb

I'd need to get the entryUUID for a record in the LDAP db via adodb ...

Someone know how could I do it ?

```
$host = 'ldap.domain.com';
$ldapbase = 'dc=domain,dc=com';
$user_name='cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com';
$password='password';

/******************************************************/

$conn=NewADOConnection( 'ldap' );
$conn->Connect( $host, $user_name, $password, $ldapbase );


function find_user($usr,$conn){
 $filter="(|(uid=$usr*))";
 $conn->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
 $rs = $conn->Execute( $filter );
 if($rs->RecordCount()>=1) {
     while ($row=$rs->FetchRow()) {
        // Blah blah blah 
         $sn=$row['sn'];
         $givenName=$row['givenName'];
         $cn=$row['cn'];
         $uid=$row['uid'];
         $mail=$row['mail'];

         // $entryUUID=$row['entryUUID']; // <-- HOW CAN I GET THIS ??
        print "\n$cn \n  $uid \n $entryUUID \n\n";
    }   
 }
 $conn->Close();

}
```

In other words , I'd like to have the same results of this query :

```
ldapsearch   -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w pwd  '(uid=$userid)' entryuuid=* entryUUID
```

I have found no info on getting hidden attributes ...

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution :

{

```
$filter="(|(uid=$usr*))";
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, array('*','entryUUID'));
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
```

}

Maybe it's useful to someone ...

David

Answer (score 0):

Operational attributes must be requested by name and the directory server must permit their retrieval by the authorization state associated with the client connection. `entryuuid` is defined in RFC4530.

Comment: Thanks Terry ... maybe I have not been clear ... I' d like to do the same in php  (  This works just fine )  :    ldapsearch   -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w pwd  '(uid=$uid)' entryuuid=* entryUUID